# What does yoroshiku (gozaimasu) mean?

Tags: word-usage

At first, I've learned that yoroshiku means nice to meet you. But then I saw it used in different cases with different meanings. So what are these meanings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

よろしく comes from the word 宜しい, which means good or acceptable, and came to be used to express consent or convenience of the listener. As such, a rough translation might be "if you find it acceptable" or "if it is convenient for you ". For example, 「よろしくお願いします」 might, outside its use as a greeting,  be translated as "I would like to make this request if you find it tolerable".

Source: http://gogen-allguide.com/yo/yoroshiku.html